How to perform Data Validation for SVC Onnx Model in STM32CubeMX
I have a SVC (Support Vector Classifier) model that has been generated and validated in python using Scikit Learn, I have then produced an ONNX file to be used in STM32CubeMX.
When I move this model to the STM32CubeMX software, I have been successful running the "analyze" and "validate on desktop" (with random numbers) options.
I would now like to run the validate on desktop with my own input and expected outputs (the same used in the python script).
I have the script setup to output a probabilities and labels file. I would like to understand if/how it's possible to set multiple outputs in STM32CubeMX. The UI suggests it can take multiple outputs, but trying in the UI and on the CLI interface this isnt possible.
The specific error being thrown is 1+2 data files are expected, which I believe should be the input, then the probabilities and labels as output.
STEdgeAI Core v9.0.0-19802 
Setting validation data... 
E204(ValParamError): 1+2 data files are expected

I believe the formats should be like the below, but I would like to know if the format that is expected in the output file(s) is actually different from what is suggested.
input 1/1          :   'input', f32(1x5), 20 Bytes, activations                                            
output 1/2         :   'output_label', int32(1x1), 4 Bytes, activations                                    
output 2/2         :   'output_probability', f32(1x1x2x2), 16 Bytes, activations

I was expecting that the input file (X_test), should produce the labels and probabilities output from the equivalent python script. Therefore reproducing the same results from python, in the STM32CubeMX report.
I have also tried to merge the labels and probabilities into a single file, but this does not seem to be accepted. I have also looked at the inputs/outputs from the random numbers and tried to use this in the validate using inputs and outputs step to no avail.
A minimal example/a link to an example of data validation using STM32CubeMX would be very helpful.
